# Is it true that two thirds of available bitcoins have already been mined?

Tags: reward-schedule

The following commentator [writes](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/ameer-rosic-/ethereum-vs-bitcoin-whats_b_13735404.html):

> More than two-thirds of all available bitcoin have already been mined, with the majority going to early miners.

My question is: **Is it true that two thirds of available bitcoins have already been mined?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is true, as seen here: http://www.bitcoinblockhalf.com/

As of writing this answer, just over 16.6 million BTC has been mined, out of a total of just under 21 million, which is around 79% of the total amount of bitcoin ever going to be created.